# Python 2D table lookup by labels

Tags: python

I have a two dimensional table here: [image]

X axis is the width (labeled 24 to 68 in bold font), and Y axis is the height (18 to 84 in bold). I want the user to be able to enter via prompt:

```
width = input("Enter width: ")
height = input("Enter height: ")
```

and lookup and print the corresponding value on this table.

My crude solution started off just defining a matrix:

```
list1 = [
[229, 252, 275],
[242, 266, 289],
[256, 280, 305]]
```

and looking up the values:

```
if width == "20" and height == "32": 
    print(list1[0][0])
elif width == "20" and height == "36": 
    print(list1[0][1])
```

This would end up being a ton of work. I have other tables like this which are even bigger. There's gotta be an easier way to look up a value on a table based on their column and row labels.

I've checked around and I couldn't find anything like what I need. I'd really like to keep this all Python if possible. Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at pandas, it supports value lookup and will be fast for what you are after

Comment: Your example list doesn't match the table; your example using `if`s doesn't, match either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you cannot be sure that the indices can be calculated by the labels, you can create two auxiliary tables which contain the column and row labels:

```
widths = [24, 28, 32, ...]
heights = [18, 24, 30, ...]
```

And then look up the table like this:

```
list1[widths.index(width)][heights.index(height)]
```

Or you can invert the two auxiliary tables to directly map from the label to the index:

```
width_idx = {w: i for i, w in enumerate(widths)}
height_idx = {h: i for i, h in enumerate(heights)}
```

And then you can do:

```
list1[width_idx[width]][height_idx[height]]
```

Comment: What would `widths[20]` yield?

Comment: The 21st entry of the list (if it is that long - if it's not, then you'll get an IndexError).

Comment: Sorry; I meant `widths.index(20)`.  Unless that yields `0`, it won't produce the result described in the example given.

Comment: Well, that would be either the index of 20 in the list, or if it's not contained some exception would be raised.

Comment: 20 isn't in the list, so an exception would be raised.  But the example given uses 20; hence, your solution fails on the example.

Comment: That's why it is an example. I used the numbers shown in the picture, the example happens to use different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could create functions to map widths/heights to list indices, so you could do something like `list1[widthIndex("20")][heightIndex("32")]`.  I suggest functions because, from your example, not all widths/heights are directly represented in the table.  This functions might look about as ugly as your `if`s, but at least there would only be 2n and not n^2 of them; nd since your table is rather regular, a formula involving dividing by 6 or 4 might make it pretty compact.